# MapView - how to disable it and keep it swipeable to left and right fragments?

Tags: android-mapview

What I'm trying to do is to make an "untouchable map". I need to be it kind of a background instead of a real map, and I need to keep it swipeable to left and right fragments. How can I implement that? I've tried to put a layer overlay, but it doesn't work, it's keep focusing on the map when I try to swipe to other fragment. Maybe there is a "switch" for the XML part? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);` - this is exactly what I was looking for.